Female Manifestations of Evil?
So, I have two evil "Beyond Mortal Existence" figures. A male and a female. I have plenty of options for naming the male one. Like the Devil, Satan, Beelzebub, Iblis, Azazil etc. However I am coming short on names for the female one. What are some historical/mythological/religious female personifications of evil?

Have you tried typing that very question in a search engine?

@L.Dutch Yes, and this was the first result. Other results were also similar. There is something wrong with google.

"evil female deities" seems to give better results

You might get better results at the Mythology & Folklore substack.

Names are entirely arbitrary and subjective. Questions where every answer is equally valid like this are not appropriate for this site.

I searched for names of evil female deities and was rewarded with a more than satisfactory starting point. Please keep in mind that you can ask anything in our chatroom, The Factory Floor. That would have been an excellent place to ask this question. We explain that in the [help/on-topic], which I hope you'll read in greater detail.

It depends on what tradition you are going with
The modern idea of the devil is an amalgamation of several different pagan deities that have all been seen as the manifestation of the Devil at various time periods.  Likewise there is a female counterpart that has permeated throughout most of Western history only to be recently supplanted all together.
Taweret if you want to go with Ancient Egyption
This is perhaps the oldest known name for a female goddess that directly represents the embodiment of evil.  She was the wife of Apep, the Egyption God of darkness and disorder who was the diametric opposition to Ra, the God of light and order.  In Egyption mythology, the conflict between good and evil was understood to be a conflict between Ra and Apep and thier respective wives Hathor and Taweret.  This narrative heavily influenced the Canaanite mythos that later became the foundation for the modern idea of God and the Devil.
Anat if want to go with a more Proto-Judaic feel
Originally, the Canaanite's had no "devil" in the sense that they did not perceive any of thier gods as "evil", but sacrifices, including human sacrifice, was common part of thier religion.  The idea of Good and Evil Gods in the Canaanite religions seems to have evolved when Abraham who worshiping El declared that El wanted the Human sacrifices to end.  Since Ba'al was the direct rival of El, and the followers of Ba'al continued to practice human sacrifices, this created a diametric opposition within the religion where El was "Good" and Ba'al was "Evil".
Between this and the Egyption Exile, the Abrahamic religion based on El worship grew to mirror the Egyption rivalry between Ra and Apep.  In the Proto-Jewish tradition, Anat was Ba'al's sister, wife, and the Goddess of War and Strife making here the female counterpart to the evil one.
Since you seem to be pulling from Judeo-Christian names for the devil, this name is probably the most appropriate, but it may be too obscure for very many readers to get.
Diktynna if you are targeting Greek
Before Judaism cemented into a monotheistic religion, they evolved the idea that El "the most high" was the only God you should worship, but that El created many divine beings which we now call angels, but that many of these angels rebelled to become the pagan gods and goddesses.  When the Jews came into contact with the Greek Pagans who still worshiped many gods, they vilified these gods by calling them demons, but fundamentally believed these to be angels who rebelled against God seeking to become gods themselves.
Meanwhile, the Greek world was torn apart by the Minoan Cretans who worshiped the "Great Goddess" Diktynna who was personified by the serpent. It has long been known that the goddess Diktynna and the symbol of the serpent came to be hated across the Ancient World.  However, recent scholarship now suggests that it was a direct result of the Minoan "Sea People" genocides across the Eastern Mediterranean that caused the Bronze Age Collapse that lead to Diktynna being seen as a universal symbol of evil among both the Greeks and Canaanites.
Hel if you are targeting the Norse Tradition
The last major pantheon in Europe was the Norse pantheon, and like the Canaanites, Greeks, and Romans before them, the Norse gods were associated with demons, and this association still has profound impacts on the English language today.
Hel was the Norse Goddess of Death, and was for a long time considered synonymous with the Devil in the English speaking world. She is where the English language gets the word Hell from.  The concept of "going to Hell" when you die did not start off meaning going to a place, but to the goddess Hel who takes the souls of the damned.
Of the names for "evil" goddesses that a modern reader might recognize, this is probably the best option, although the strong association with Norse mythology might seem off if you pair it with one of the Judeo-Christian names for the devil.
Conclusion
These are only some possible options, because just as there are many names for the male manifestation of evil: Devil, Satan, Beelzebub, Iblis, Azazil, etc.  The female manifestation has just about as many versions.  So, you can either pick whichever makes the most sense for your setting, or ride on the idea that she goes by many different names impressing on the idea that she is so old and universal that no one name encompasses her.

Lilith (as seen in Supernatural, but google it!); I think they even have other female evil characters.

Thanks,  but I already know that one, but was hoping for more from the diverse cultures of the world.

Do you already have Karen?

Lilith is also kind of seen as subordinate to the Devil, but my female evil is equal.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

@surprisedog How does this not answer the question? The question asked for "female manifestations of evil". The poster gave the name of a mythical female person reputed to be greatly evil. Sounds to me like that's exactly what the OP was asking for.

And OP gave as an example the Devil, Satan, Beezelbub.. Which come from the same religion that lilith does...

Partial frame challenge that is also a straight answer:
Powerful mythological beings are not characters, they are the personifications of ideas of character-ness. Consequently, sexes in mythology reflect mythic conceptions of the sexes. By picking male and female creatures from mythology, you're locking in a host of millennia-old cultural tropes and encoding them as realities of your world. If this is what you want, awesome. If this is not what you want... consider just making up a name that's bad-sounding and female coded in English.
Evil (or at least opposed-to-rightness) mythic females can...

Afflict women in their specifically female activities, especially childbearing. Lashmatu (Babylonian demon) is female because she causes miscarriages, infant mortality, and death in childbirth.

Corrupt others, especially male men and male gods, away from masculine virtues, such as toughness, boldness, self-denial, and honor as culturally defined. Kakia (Greek goddess) is female because she tempts gods and men with ease, vice, and the fruits of others' labors.

Sexually manipulate men to their destruction. Gumiho (Korean demon) is female because she seduces men and then eats the best parts of them and leaves their corpses to rot.

Interact/ed with the world through a process analogous to female sexual reproduction: absorb, transmute, gestate, produce. Loviatar (Finnish goddess) is female because she gives absorbs neutral elements, transmutes them, gestates, and births/birthed; she is evil because what she births is the diseases.

Represent untamed, chaotic nature defying the ordering (masculine) influence. Tiamat (Babylonian goddess) is female among other reasons because she personifies the primordial chaos of the universe.



I object very strongly against the affirmation that mythological beings are not characters. They definitely are. I have no idea what the phrase "personifications of characterness" is even supposed to mean. And saying that, for example, Tiamat was female because this or that assumes knowledge about ancient people which I would find very hard to justify. All we know is that she was female. Why she was female we don't know. (And she is very dead; she was killed by Marduk. It is improper to refer to her in the present tense.)

Immediate thoughts are Asherah and Astarte, pagan goddesses. Jezebel comes to mind, not a supernatural figure but a woman whose name became almost synonymous with "evil woman" because of the condemnation of her in the Bible. Mata Hari brings to mind a temptress, though maybe not the best example because of debatable historical issues. In Greek mythology, Medusa was an evil female supernatural being. Also in Greek mythology there are the three Furies, Alecto, Megaera, and Tisiphone. Those names may be too obscure for most readers to recognize, though.
You could search the Internet for "evil female spirits" or "female demons" or the like. I just tried that and most of the names it turned up are pretty obscure, like from the mythologies of religions that most English-speakers never heard of. It might be amusing to use an obscure name that your readers won't recognize just to give the "in joke" feeling to those who do, but frankly at that point I think you're just as well off to make up names.

Ishtar is not evil at all. She is the great goddess of love. Same for Asherah, who is the Supreme Goddess. And the Furies or Erinyes are not evil in themselves; on the contrary, they are the avengers of last resort, the divine forces which won't let evil go unpunished.

@AlexP To a Jew or a Christian, and I'd guess to a Muslim, any pagan goddess is evil. I don't have my copy of "Stories from Ancient Canaan" handy but there is one in there where a goddess threatens and badgers the chief god, El, which would make her maybe not evil per se but decidedly unlikable. I think it was Asherah but maybe I'm mis-remembering. Yes, the Erinyes weren't exactly "evil", but they were harsh and relentless. To someone seeking justice, they might seem good. To someone who was their target, they would seem evil.
